# How to yield a sub-template(component) in a layout file in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to yield a piece of html into the navbar of a particular route in Angular 2. So this is not a part of the body component but is a part of the layout in the header of the page. How di i do this in angular 2?
This is what I did in AngularJS.

```
//header.html .. which is a partial within the layout

<div class="nav-wrapper">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ui-view="navbar_options">
        <li>

           <a href="" trigger-resize="" ng-click="app.layout.isCollapsed = !app.layout.isCollapsed" class="hidden-xs"> <em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>
           </a>

           <a href="" ng-click="app.asideToggled = !app.asideToggled" class="visible-xs sidebar-toggle"> <em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>
           </a>
        </li>

     </ul>
</div>





//routes.config.js

.state('app.xyz', {

          url: '/jobs/:jobID',
          views:{
          '': {title: 'abc',
          templateUrl: helper.basepath('path/xyz.html'),
          controller: 'myController',
          },
          'navbar_options': {title: 'my_page',
          templateUrl: helper.basepath('path/xyz_navbar.html'),

          controller: 'myController'}

          }
      })
```

I want to achieve the same in Angular 2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to display a component in the navbar based on a certain route, but the main body of the page is also going to be updated on the route change. If I were you, I would use a "Secondary Route". I believe they are also referred to as "Named Routes"

Normally, your web page would be something like this:

```
<div class="app-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This works great if you are updating only one portion of your web page. If you want to update more than one portion, you need to provide several routes and they are named. They look like this:

```
<router-outlet name="myroute"></router-outlet>
```

I am guessing you will want one of these named routers in your navbar and then you have to create a link which places data in the named route... That link would look something like this:

```
<button md-button [routerLink]="['/mainroute', {outlets: {'myroute': ['routnamehere']}}]">
    Open Two Routes
</button>
```

Comment: very close to what i am looking for. is there anyway i can directly access this through a path ? i.e. when i go to the route '/mymainroute', the named routeoutlet is loaded as a part of the page load itself as opposed to having a button with additional parameters to retrieve my named outlet .

Comment: I am not aware of any way to load two outlets without specifying them in the routerLink.

Comment: I would say use a nested route as one link would load a route and then a sub-route, but it appears this would not work as Nested routes load one template inside the other and it appears you want templates in two different areas of your web page.

Comment: yes- the second issue is that the router-outlets that i want displayed are not at the same component (parent/child) level. So the navbar which i want to be added is a part of the layout file and the rest of the html file is within a module that further loads child components- hence this becomes a nested component within another router-outlet(app-level) and hence, when i try to yield the link from within my module, it does not understand my layout-level named router-outlet.

Comment: If i add the named router-outlet within the current module, it understands and yields the component correctly but this is not what i am looking for.